# call method of result of await - intermediate value not resolved yet

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

Say I have an await expression that should return an array, like so:

```
let prompts = (await requestp('get', `${cdtAPIUrl}/prompts`, headers)).slice(0, 3);
```

I get this error, however:

> TypeError: (intermediate value).slice is not a function

is there a way to call something on the "intermediate value" or should I do this instead:

```
  let $prompts = await requestp('get', `${cdtAPIUrl}/prompts`, headers);
  let prompts = $prompts.slice(0,3);
```

Comment: What does the promise that `requestp()` returns actually resolve to?  What is the resolved value?

Comment: Your first code does exactly the same as your second. If there's an error, that just suggests that `requestp()` did not fulfill with an array or anything with a `.slice` method.

Comment: Yeah you're probably right, I guess it's unfortunate that "intermediate value" is used instead of the actual value, which is clearly available somewhere.

Comment: (An alternative explanation would be that your transpiler messed up, but that's rather unlikely. If you are using a transpiler, it's also easy to rule out by just inspecting the transpilation result).

Comment: yeah no transpiler here

Comment: What environment is it that reports the "intermediate value"? Did you try other engines? You might want to report the issue in their bug tracking system.

Comment: As I asked in the very first comment.  What IS the resolved value?

Comment: It was an object `{}`, without a slice method on it :) so you were correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a strange error message, but @Bergi is correct - the result being returned by the await expression, was not an array, which is why the runtime errored out.

For example:

```
let val = (await 4).slice(x);
```

will give you the error from the original question.

whereas:

```
let val = (await []).slice(x);
```

should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

the error `TypeError: (intermediate value).slice is not a function`
means that the `$prompts` is not an array.

You should try to debug or log this value before calling `let prompts = $prompts.slice(0,3);`